# R function/loop to get column wise values

Tags: r, list, loops, get, element

```
GT  VB  WM
23  34  28
34  27  33
    44  46
    54
```

I have a data like above in a csv file.I need a R script to retrieve by column wise values either by loop or function when passing arguments as a variable name.Ex. When I type GT I should get relevant values without NA like

```
GT
23 34
```

Comment: Use `na.omit(df$GT)`

Answer (score 0):

This

```
lapply(df, na.omit)
```

creates a list of vector where all `NA`s are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on all the information you have given, the following R commands (an "R script") will do this for you. I'm assuming that the CSV file contains 3 columns called GT, VB and WM in the first row and there are 4 rows of data starting in row 2. I'm also assuming that the file is in fact a comma separated file format, meaning that the columns (including the header row) is separated by commas.

```
df <- read.csv("myfile.csv")
```

If you don't want NA values to appear whenever you type the name of the column, you'll have to remove the NA from each element of the data frame, saving the results as a list (since a data frame cannot have columns of unequal length), using either `lapply` or `sapply`.

```
df.list <- sapply(df, FUN=function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

And then attach to it:

```
attach(df.list)
```

Typing the names of the columns should return the original values with NA omitted.

```
GT  
[1] 23 34

VB
[1] 34 27 44 54

WM
[1] 28 33 46
```

When you are finished, detach from this modified R object as it is good practice to do so.

```
detach(df.list) # Good practice
```

And this does exactly what you said. No more and no less.

**data**

```
library(tibble)
df <- tribble(~GT,  ~VB,  ~WM,
23,  34,  28,
34,  27,  33,
NA,  44,  46,
NA,  54,  NA)
```